# C# lambda limit with include

Tags: c#, lambda, limit, take

I have this piece of code.

```
return Folder.GetAllWithInclude(x => x.SubFolder).Take(5);
```

This code returns 5 Folder items. What I want to do is limit Subfolder to 5 instead of limiting Folder to 5. I have tried the following

```
return Folder.GetAllWithInclude(x => x.SubFolder.Take(5));
```

but it doesn't seem to do the trick.

I might be missing the proper syntax here.

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Without knowing what `GetAllWithInclude` returns precisely, there might be better options, but in theory the following should work: `return Folder.GetAllWithInclude(x => x.SubFolder).SelectMany(s=>s).Take(5);`

Comment: Hi @Me.Name but I still have to return the complete Folder records together with its 5 Subfolder items.

Comment: Ah right. And if the first folder contains 3 items and a second 5, it should return a folder with 3 and a folder with 2 items? It would seem that would be easier to implement in the `GetAllWithInclude` method. Is that a custom method or some library method I'm unaware of?

Comment: Ohhhh I'm sorry its a custom method lets say we have 2 Folders, the #1 folder contains 6 subfolders and #2 folder contains 2 subfolders then the code should return 2folders with the #1 folder containing only 5 subfolders while #2 folder still contains 2 subfolders.

Comment: No problem, but could you include the method in your post? Perhaps the method itself could be expanded with an optional parameter to restrict the maximum subfolders (or a dynamic criterium).  If it can't be implemented in the GetAllWithInclude method, the alternatives would depend on what the object returned by GetAllWithInclude looks like.

Answer (score 2):

There's no method for `Include(Where Expression)`. If you are using Include you will always load all the records.

**Update**

you can use `Projection` for this problem

```
Folder.Select(F => new
        {
            FolderName = F.FolderName,
            SubFolders = F.SubFolders.Take(5)
        }).ToList().Select(F => new Folder()
        {
            FolderName = F.FolderName,
            SubFolders = F.SubFolders
        };
```

Comment: but we can always use .Take() to limit right? I don't know how to limit the subclasses return.

Comment: @JackFrother you can't use Take() for include either